# How does the Linux kernel locate fragments of the swap file when waking from hibernation?

Tags: swap, hibernate

I understand that when waking from hibernation, the kernel does not read the swap file via the filesystem but instead directly from the block device; this is why the `resume_offset` kernel parameter is required. However, the file may be fragmented (the kernel [documentation](https://docs.kernel.org/power/swsusp-and-swap-files.html) even says, "swap files need not be contiguous"). How does the kernel locate the fragments of the file without using the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

What you read is not true.

Resume is "simple": a full, normal Linux boots, reads the filesystem, which it can do because it's a normal Linux, reads the swap file from the filesystem into RAM, loads the kernel that should work with this state, and executes it.

I think you might be reading decade-old documents!

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct.

Comment: Oh, in as far, @karel?